# How to add Range-interval partition to existing table in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, partition

I am currently struggling with performance issues in an old system with badly defined partitions.
The offending table is defined like this:

```
create table Ver
(
   Ver_id             number (15) not null,
   Vmo_enddate        date null,
   Vmo_til_version    number (6) not null
)
partition by range (Vmo_til_version)
   interval ( 1 )
   subpartition by range
   (Vmo_enddate)
   subpartition template (
      subpartition
         Y2024
         values less than
            (to_date (' 2024-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
      subpartition Future values less than (Maxvalue))
(
   partition
      Ver1
      values less than (2)
      (
         subpartition
            Ver1_y2024
            values less than
               (to_date (' 2024-01-01 00:00:00',
                         'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
                         'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
         subpartition Ver1_future values less than (Maxvalue)),
   partition
      values less than (100000)
      (
         subpartition
            values less than
               (to_date (' 2024-01-01 00:00:00',
                         'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
                         'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')),
         subpartition values less than (Maxvalue)));
```

There are many more subpartitions and hundreds of main partitions, but neither have been expanded since the person responsible for the system retired a few years ago.
Therefore, all data since 2020 lands in the maxvalue partition, which now contains billions of rows instead of millions per month and it's killing performance.

Oracle is not exactly my strongest skill. I have figured out how to expand the subpartition template, but i cant for the life of me figure out how to add new main partitions. My thought is that "simply" adding partitions for the next several years is the cheapest solution for now, until resources are freed up to solve it for real.
Is it possible to do to an existing table or do i need to remake it as a new table?

Comment: If you try to fix this in place, you'll have to split the maxvalue partition repeatedly. That isn't a very efficient option. I recommend rebuilding the table. Create a table with the proper partitioning scheme, load it from the old table, then swap their names. That of course requires some down time as you can't have changes happening to the old table after you've begun data movement and before you've swapped their names at the end. But this is by far the most efficient method. For the load you can use parallel dml before creating any indexes or foreign keys for maximum speed.

Comment: And, I would recommend switching your partition and subpartitions - let your date range be your main partitions, interval by year (set the interval). That way you never have a maxvalue partition issue again. Your vmo_til_version would be your subpartitions and be defined as list. You may not even need those subpartitions - evaluate the reason why vmo_til_version is a partitioning key in the first place and maybe you can simplify by not having subpartitions at all. If you do need it, consider auto list.

Comment: The vmo_version is the nomenclature version of the data while the enddate is the month the data is received. It is a 300K lines of code system and this particular table is used in several hundred queries, so the ramifications of changing the structure of the partitions is a bit scary.

Comment: Doing the new correct table -> move data -> rename that you suggest was one of my first thought, so i will try that one. Thank you for the feedback :)